# Fogbugz EBS: should I stop my clock when working on non-fogbugz tasks?

Tags: fogbugz

On my current project I mark down 80% of my time as spent on fogbugz tasks, and 20% on other things.

What is the correct way for me to update the "working on" status?  Should I switch it to "nothing" for the 20% of other activity, or is that taken account of automatically?

If I do switch to "working on nothing" when doing other activities, how can I keep track of how accurate my 20%/80% estimate was in the long run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can think of, if nobody else answers this, is to create a schedule item for my "other tasks" and assign time to this item, so I can keep track of how realistic my 80/20 estimate is.

If I don't want this to affect my estimation history (as it's not a programming issue) I think it's possible to discard the estimate from my estimation history.

Answer (score 1):

It takes this into account automatically. You don't need to stop and start the clock.  If you work 8 hours a day, it will assume 1.6 hrs were spent doing other things (like lunch).

Comment: I see - thanks - so I don't need to stop the clock, but I should create another task if I want to keep track of whether my 80/20 estimate was accurate?

Comment: I have now seen there is a script to allow creation of weekly scheduled tasks, maybe this is the thing to do